# Unknown version specified for initialization: 3.1.0 schemaTool failed

Tags: hadoop, hive, schema, derby, hive-metastore

I installed Hive on Windows 10 and I am using Cygwin to use the schemaTool utility in order to initialize metastore, as it is not compatible with the Windows Terminal.

I attempt to run the following command:

`$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema --verbose`

And I am getting the following error:

```
Metastore connection URL:        jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
Metastore connection User:       APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 3.1.0
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified for initialization: 3.1.0
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified for initialization: 3.1.0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreSchemaInfo.generateInitFileName(MetaStoreSchemaInfo.java:137)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:585)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:567)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1517)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

My Hadoop version is 3.2.0 and my Hive version is 3.1.2.

Comment: Did you try `Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace`?

Comment: @BryanPendleton I edited the question and have included the detailed error after using --verbose command.

Comment: According to this code github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-3/standalone-metastore/src/… it is not able to find some file. I have created a symbolic link for cygwin, and all paths are correct, still issue persists.

Comment: same problem encountered

Comment: I'm also on cygwin. In my case, it added 'e:\cygwin' prefix that ended as 'E:\cygdrive\e\apache-hive-metastore-3.0.0-bin\scripts\metastore\upgrade\derby\hive-schema-3.0.0.derby.sql'. Moving scripts to this path solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah finally I have solved it no need of Cygwin.

first download these cmds and paste them in bin folder which you might have already done

https://github.com/HadiFadl/Hive-cmd

no need to repeat it if you have already done it :)

i have created the database in mysql by create database metastore_db;

my hive_site.xml looks like this because i choosed to use mysql, write your mysql username,password in place of root root.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=false&amp;useSSL=true</value>
        <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
        <value>root</value>
        <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
        <value>root</value>
        <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

write this in cmd:

```
hive --service schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

or write this if you are using mysql as backend:

```
hive --service schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema
```

if you get output at the end like

```
Initialization script completed
schemaTool completed
```

you have successfully done it. else try to go to C:\apache-hive-3.1.2-bin\bin via cmd and then execute it.

Comment: I had the cmd files in bin folder alreayd. And I was using derby not mysql, so I didn't do any changes. But I just ran the command from hive bin folder path from cmd, and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I copied the files and I did not have to go through the process of Cygwin, thank you. I just ran hive --service schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema in the Hive Directory and the metastore was initialized.